# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Cordova onDeviceReady is not firing

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using worklight 6.0.

The deviceready event is not firing. I'm testing this in the MBS, in iOS and Android both in  Firefox and Chrome.

Here is the code I have used in `initoptions.js` file:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
     alert("device Ready")
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}
```

alert is never getting fired.

I think worklight 6.0 using cordova 2.6 version, Do I need to change the cordova.js of any other version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This check is not needed in a Worklight-based application.

As you correctly mentioned, Cordova is bundled with Worklight; Once your app successfully  launches, the `deviceReady` has already fired (internally). Otherwise, your app would not work to begin with.

App launch > Cordova initialization > Worklight framework initialization > App is "ready"

So what you need to do is to simply place your implementation code in `common\yourApp.js` (or wherever you want and then call it), w/out the `deviceReady` check.

For example, you'll note that if doing the following, it will work even w/out the check for `devicReady` first.

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    alert (device.cordova);
}
```

---

If to use the fileSystem example, which is what you are trying to do... I have done the following and it is working OK for me. I simply [followed the LocalFileSystem example from the Cordova File API page](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem).

1. New project and application
2. **Added the Android environment**

   The File API is meant for *mobile environments* and not for previewing in your *PC browser*.
   This is the reason for the error you see: `LocalFileSystem is not defined`. It has got nothing to do with `deviceReady`.
3. In `common\testapp.js` I have added the following
4. Ran the app in Android Emulator
5. In the app, I got the success alert()

   > ```
   > function wlCommonInit(){
   >     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
   > }
   >
   > function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
   >    alert("*** Success *** File system name is: " + fileSystem.name);
   > }
   >
   > function fail(evt) {
   >     alert("*** Fail *** Error code is: " + evt.target.error.code);
   > }
   > ```

To do the same when previewing the *Android environment* via Worklight Console's *MBS*, you need to make sure you have Java installed and that it is active in your browser (to view Java applets). You should then use the *File* menu on the left pane.

See these questions:

- [IBM Worklight - File API simulation in Worklight Console's MBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921561/ibm-worklight-file-api-simulation-in-worklight-consoles-mbs)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - "Capture API simulation is disabled (applet not loaded, please check your Java settings)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523287/ibm-worklight-6-0-capture-api-simulation-is-disabled-applet-not-loaded-plea)

If you are on Mac, [you need to use Java 6](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2429779?hl=en).

Comment: Hi Idan, eventhough i place the same code in my app.js file, onDeviceReady is not getting fired.

Comment: @user2967626, **you do not need it**. If your Worklight application is running, it means deviceReady has been fired. I meant place there your actual implementation code and NOT the check for deviceReady. Again, you do-not-need-this-check. This is done internally in the Worklight framework.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you will open a new question and ask there what you are actually trying to implement and what is not working for you in it (not the deviceReady part).

Comment: I put this line in myapp.js file window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);Iam getting LocalFileSytem is not defined.I think when the device is ready only this LocalFileSystem is intialized

Comment: No, it's working just fine. See my edited answer with an example at the bottom.

Comment: I have ran a sample applet program, its running on firefox, java is enabled on my browser as well. Even then The File API simulation is disabled in MBS

Comment: Then you are facing a different issue here. In any case, this question - about deviceready not being fired has been answered. I hope you now understand how this works in Worklight. Since your question is answered, please mark as Answered.

Comment: What is your OS and browser?

Comment: windows 7 and firefox 17.0

Comment: Firefox 17 is very old, try updating to the latest.

Comment: Adan,I tried with latest version of firefox i.e 24 ,But didnt help.I have tested on the real device as well, still the same problem

Comment: Then you need to describing what you are doing, because it's working here.

Comment: its wiered, now its workking on chrome and real device but not on firefox. Anyways Thanks Adan